# Adding image capture to uiview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image-capture

I want to add a photo captured from my app and display on the iPad for 2 seconds. I have a self timing photo app that counts down from 4 to 1 then takes the photo. I have it set to display a PNG image when it reaches zero. But I want to display the photo that was taken immediately after the PNG image. I am stumped.

This is part of the code that saves the image.

```
- (void)captureEnded:(CameraView *)camView {
NSLog(@"%f, %f", [camView capturedImage].size.width, [camView capturedImage].size.height);



UIImage *img = [camView capturedImage];
```

This is part of the code that displays the countdown. When the timer reaches zero "smile3" displays on screen for .2 seconds. I want the UI Image above to display following that smile3 for 2 seconds. Any thoughts?

```
if (mTimer-counter+1 == 0) {
            [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] playShutterSound];
            lblRemainPhoto.hidden = YES;
            [btnTimeCounter setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smile3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2  target:self selector:@selector(anim1) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
```